# How to use Rails' session() in a PORO

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

So i'm refactoring my code to obey the single responsibility principle. On of the things I'm doing is moving my user registration, activation and logging in to seperate models. No problems with the first two, but for the last I need to store stuff in a session.

Unfortunataly in my PORO, I'm not able to do stuff like `session['user_id'] = user.id`, I probably need to include some kind of class first. I've been digging through the Rails API, but couldn't find anything that actually has a method `session`.

So following this, I have the following questions:

1. What should I require/include to enable sessions in my PORO?
2. What could help me solve these kind of questions by myself next time? Is there some way I can do a good search in the API of Rails?

Comment: Never couple your models to the session, even if there was a way, it would be a very bad idea as then unit testing would be unnecessary more complicated (as well as debugging and refactoring)

Why can't you use instance variables within the model to maintain the state

Comment: Well, I have a login form that sends the data to the create method in SessionController. That's where I'm calling the UserLogin. I was planning for this class to handle all the logic, like checking password matches, checking that the user has confirmed his account and starting the session. Should I start the session somewhere else? I was trying to decouple the login and per page authentication to a sperate module / class.